# Invalid column name with Embedded field

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In some tests, I have an error:

```
SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column name 'contact_information_id'.

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
```

In the DB I have a **primary_contact_information_id** column instead.

It occurs when the repository tries to save an **Organisation** entity. There is a **PrimaryContact** field in the Organisation class and in **PrimaryContact** class I have the **contactInformation** field.

The project was moved from java7 to java8 and currently, I'm working on a migration from Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 5.

There was a naming strategy org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy, so for hibernate 5 I used a **CustomNamingStrategy**

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    public static final CustomNamingStrategy INSTANCE = new CustomNamingStrategy();

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }

    @Override
     public Identifier toPhysicalColumnName(Identifier name, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        return new Identifier(addUnderscores(name.getText()), name.isQuoted());
    }


    protected static String addUnderscores(String name) {
         final StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(name.replace('.', '_'));
        for (int i = 1; i < buf.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (
                    Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i - 1)) &&
                        Character.isUpperCase(buf.charAt(i)) &&
                        Character.isLowerCase(buf.charAt(i + 1))) {
                buf.insert(i++, '_');
            }
        }
        return buf.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
    }
}
```

**Organisation**

```
@Entity(name = "Organisation")
@Table(name = "organisation", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(name = "organisation_name_udx", columnNames = {"name"})})
@EntityListeners(EntityCreateListener.class)
public class Organisation implements Serializable, PatientListEntity {

    // Some fields here

    @Embedded
    @Valid
    private PrimaryContact primaryContact;

    // Some fields here
}
```

**PrimaryContact**

```
@Embeddable
public class PrimaryContact extends Person implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Valid
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "primary_contact_information_id")
    private ContactInformation contactInformation;
}
```

**ContactInformation**

```
@Entity(name = "ContactInformation")
@Table(name = "contact_information")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContactInformation implements Serializable {
public static final int MAX_PHONENUMBERS = 5;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Valid
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
private Address address = new Address();

@RFCEmail
@Size(max = RFCEmailValidator.EMAIL_TOTAL_MAX_LENGTH)
private String email = "";

@Valid
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "number", column = @Column(name = "phone_number_0")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "phone_type_0"))})
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber0;

@Valid
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "number", column = @Column(name = "phone_number_1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "phone_type_1"))})
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber1;

@Valid
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "number", column = @Column(name = "phone_number_2")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "phone_type_2"))})
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber2;

@Valid
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "number", column = @Column(name = "phone_number_3")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "phone_type_3"))})
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber3;

@Valid
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "number", column = @Column(name = "phone_number_4")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "phone_type_4"))})
private PhoneNumber phoneNumber4;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "time_zone_code")
private TimeZone timeZone;
}
```

As you can see, there is a @JoinColumn(name = "primary_contact_information_id")  under the contactInformation field, but it doesn't help.

***!!! UPDATED !!!***

It looks like this strange behavior occurs because of my custom naming strategy. So, I decided to remove it at all. But now, after adding necessary `@Column` annotations I receive a new error:

```
BatchUpdateException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "application_dme_provider_fk1". The conflict occurred in database "ruslans_00_develop_dev_easycare", table "dbo.application", column 'application_code'.], SQL: update application_dme_provider set application_code=? where application_code=? and party_id=? and party_role_type_code=?
```

Comment: You haven't posted `ContactInformation` entity. Does it have `contactInformationId` field?

Comment: Added ContactInformation entity, but there is no contactInformationId field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because of default naming strategy in Hibernate 5. It adds "_id" for each (**OneToOne, OneToMany, ManyToMany**) relations. 
`@JoinColumn(name = <correct_name_from_db>)` will fix it.

In my case, there was one more **ContactInformation** field without **JoinColumn** annotation.